# Python Tornado: how can I make this asynchronous ?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, tornado

In the below code, when I do message_response.get(), it will make this particular code synchronous. Now is there a way I can make this aynchronous? Just push the code to a broker. And once celery worker is done with the task, I can write the result back to the client?

```
import tornado.websocket
from celery_main import do_something_celery_task


class HomePageRequestHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def on_message(self, message):
        message_response = do_something_celery_task.apply_async((message,))
        # How can this be a non blocking call? 
        self.write_message(message_response.get())

    def open(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on [coroutines](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html)?

Comment: I want to use task queuing, would like to monitor no. of requests are there and stuffs. Is there a way around for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this: https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery
You'll have code like this, but I don't run it.

```
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler

class WebSocketBase(WebSocketHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def on_message(self, message):
        response = yield gen.Task(tasks.sleep.apply_async, args=[3])
        self.write_message(str(response.result))
```